# Text Overflowing container after adding height:auto to container

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage where text is overflowing a container div, even after applying `height:auto;` to the containing div. The make up of the page looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper"> 

    <div id="inner_wrapper">

        <div id="content_left">
                <div class="main_content_text">
                      Overflowing text
                </div><!--end of main_content_text-->
        </div><!--end of content_left-->

        <div id="content_right">
        </div><!--end of content_right-->

    </div><!--end of inner_wrapper-->
 </div><!--end of wrapper-->
 </body>
 </html>
```

The CSS I'm using looks like this :

```
#inner_wrapper{
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
min-height: 900px;
height: auto;
margin: 0px auto;
  }

#content_left{
padding: 10px;
margin: 10px 10px 30px 20px;
width: 57%;
min-height: 300px;
float: left;
 }

.main_content_text{
width: 625px;
height: auto;
font-weight: normal;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro','Ubuntu Light','Ubuntu Condensed',Ubuntu,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 20px;
margin-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

My the page I'm applying it on is here [Website](http://types4u.org/blog/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following rule:

```css
#inner_wrapper:after { 
  content: " "; 
  display: block; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  clear: both; 
  height: 0; 
}
```

It will clear the floats, no need for adding additional `<div class="clear">` elements

Answer (score 0):

set the `overflow:auto` for the div you need!